# Which should I change to consume more RAM?

Tags: mariadb, performance, performance-tuning

I have a VPS server in Vultr of 4GB RAM.

#### Services

- Mysql
- Nginx
- PHP7
- Memcached

#### Platforms

- Prosper202 - 10GB database
- Wordpress - 100MB database

Right now I'm using maximum 37% of RAM. It works very well for me, but I would like to take better advantage of the server so my question is:

What values should rise?
Or what things in the database should take priority when consuming more RAM?

My configuration is:

```
# MariaDB database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this file to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
max_user_connections=45
max_connections=100
max_connect_errors=20
#max_connections        = 500 #ESTO LO CAMBIO SEGUN LA MEMORIA DEL SERVIDOR. POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,1 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER. Con 1 GB de RAM que no puede manejar 200 conexiones, que puede bloquear el servidor

connect_timeout=2
#connect_timeout        = 600
wait_timeout=60
#wait_timeout       = 86400 #Agregue esto a su my.cnf para reducir las conexiones inactivas comer hasta la memoria RAM

max_allowed_packet=10M
#max_allowed_packet = 32M
thread_cache_size=128
#thread_cache_size       = 50 #POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,05 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
sort_buffer_size=256K
#sort_buffer_size   = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size=50M
#tmp_table_size     = 33M #ESTO LO CAMBIO SEGUN LA MEMORIA DEL SERVIDOR. POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,5 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
max_heap_table_size=50M
#max_heap_table_size    = 33M #ESTO LO CAMBIO SEGUN LA MEMORIA DEL SERVIDOR. POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,5 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
join_buffer_size=2M
table_cache=1000

#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover_options = FORCE,BACKUP
key_buffer=500M
#key_buffer_size        = 32M #POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,032 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
open_files_limit               = 65535
#open-files-limit   = 2000 #POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 65,535 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache    = 4096 #POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 4,096 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
#myisam_sort_buffer_size    = 512M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size=128K
#read_buffer_size   = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
#read_rnd_buffer_size   = 1M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
query_cache_limit=20M
#query_cache_limit      = 128K #ESTO LO CAMBIO SEGUN LA MEMORIA DEL SERVIDOR. POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,002 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
#query_cache_size       = 64M #ESTO LO CAMBIO SEGUN LA MEMORIA DEL SERVIDOR. POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,256 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
query_cache_size=20M
#query_cache_size               = 8M
query_cache_type=1
#query_cache_type               = 0
# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
#query_cache_type       = DEMAND
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# we do want to know about network errors and such
log_warnings        = 2
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={0|1}]
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan
log_error                      = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#report_host        = master1
#auto_increment_increment = 2
#auto_increment_offset  = 1
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog        = 1
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
# slaves
#relay_log      = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
#relay_log_index    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
#relay_log_info_file    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
#log_slave_updates
#read_only
#
# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode       = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
# you can't just change log file size, requires special procedure
#innodb_log_file_size   = 50M #POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,064 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size    = 2G #ESTO INDICA LA CANTIDAD DE MEMORIA QUE USA LA BASE DE DATOS. POR CADA MEGA DE RAM LO MULTIPLICO POR 0,6 Y LO QUE ME DA ES EL VARLOR QUE TENGO QUE PONER
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group      = 2
innodb_log_file_size           = 128M

#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=32M



#[mysqldump]
#quick
#quote-names
#max_allowed_packet = 32M
##max_connect_errors             = 100000000
#skip_name_resolve
#sql_mode                       = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
#sysdate_is_now                 = 1
#innodb                         = FORCE
#innodb_strict_mode             = 1

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completion

#[isamchk]
#key_buffer=500M
#key_buffer     = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

My results are:

```
    [OK] Logged in using credentials from debian maintenance account.
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.6.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.1.21-MariaDB-1~xenial
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MRG_MyISAM +SEQUENCE 
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 1)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 9G (Tables: 567)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 18

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] There is no anonymous account in all database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] User 'wpoffline@%' hasn't specific host restriction.
[--] There is 605 basic passwords in the list.

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 34m 15s (52K q [25.447 qps], 3K conn, TX: 6B, RX: 17M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 41% / 59%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Total buffers: 814.0M global + 6.7M per thread (100 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 860.6M (21.78% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.4G (37.45% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/52K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 7% (7/100)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/3819)
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 8.9% (1K cached / 19K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 20 sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 213
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 45% (549 on disk / 1K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (7 created / 3K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (770 open / 776 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (60/16K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (6M immediate / 6M locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 100.00% ( 27085 Memory / 27085 Total)

-------- MyISAM Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.3% (95M used / 524M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 500.0M/123.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 90.0% (20 cached / 2 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 100.0M/9.6G
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool <= 1G and innodb_buffer_pool_instances(!=1).
[OK] InnoDB Used buffer: 84.00% (5375 used/ 6399 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.68% (46117648 hits/ 46267049 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 29084 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_limit (> 20M, or use smaller result sets)
    join_buffer_size (> 2.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    tmp_table_size (> 50M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 50M)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 9G) if possible.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances (=1)
```

I want to increase memory usage because the admin zone goes a little slow. Since the database has a current size of 10GB.

By increasing the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` the administrator zone loads faster.

The administrator is the only one who has to load historical data. The remaining visitors only write in the database. Just some read the database.

Comment: What's "admin zone"? Why do you think that increased memory usage will make it faster? What does it have to do with the database size of 10 GB?

Answer (score 1):

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100M` is indeed very small - as you have the spare RAM you could increase it, it's the main cache for InnoDB (where you keep your tables ).

Note: as only the admin uses that page then I don't think your cache will be very effective.
take a look at your disk read_ahead - you could probably gain some by tuning your IO system.

also, many of your queries don't use index - consider indexing and limiting the amount of historic data returned to the admin (I doubt he wants everything that ever happened :) ).
also look at `join_buffer_size` - it shouldn't be very high but as you're missing indexes it might help.

Good luck,
 - Jony

Comment: Good but we don't know if the tables use MyISAM or InnoDB or both. They have allocated 500MB to MyISAM's key buffer.

Comment: Hi, but we do:
`InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 100.0M/9.6G`
and `Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 500.0M/123.0K`

he uses 9.6GB of InnoDB - his DB is about 10GB he says... - he uses InnoDB.
MyISAM only has 123K - it's really nothing...

Comment: Oh, it's in the tuner output, didn't notice.